# why visual studio 2010 generated dll size larger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a dll project that was created in VC++ 2008. The released dll file after building this project in VS 2008 is 299kB.
But, when I convert the project to VC++ 2010, the size of the output dll grows significantly!!! (1643kB !!!)

Why is the output dll file generated by Visual Studio 2010 so much larger?

Are there any settings in Visual Studio 2010 which I could edit, to get a smaller output file released?

Comment: Did you compare the compiler and linker flags that are actually passed to the compiler and linker? The conversion wizard might change the project settings slightly, to make it e.g. more safe.

Comment: Is runtime static or dynamic? See **Project Properties - C++ - Code Generation - Runtime Library.**

Comment: in Project Properties - C++ - Code Generation - Runtime Library set to "Multi-threaded (/MT)"

Answer (score 1):

The `/MT` flag means you're *statically* linking in the C runtime library.

Presumably, in your previous project in VS 2008, you were *dynamically* linking to the runtime library, which will make the output file smaller because it doesn't have to embed all of the required functionality from the C runtime library in your DLL.

The fix is simple, just change the setting to `/MD`. Dynamic linking is much preferred anyway.

Comment: my dll will use in any program languas(C#, VB , VC, ...) . i should use "Use MFC in a Static Library" then don't choose /MT flag!!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. MFC has nothing to do with the C runtime library. One can be linked statically while the other is linked dynamically, or vice versa. None of this has any effect on whether the DLL can be called from another programming language.